# How to fix error 'The request is missing a valid API key' in Kotlin Retrofit for Google Translation API?

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, retrofit, google-translation-api

I use retrofit and Rapid api to use Google translation api but i have an error:

```
{
    "code" : 403,
    "errors" : [{
      "domain" : "global",
      "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
      "reason" : "forbidden"
    }],
    "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

Here my code using retrofit

```
interface GoogleTranslationApi {

    @POST("language/translate/v2")
    @Headers(
        "X-RapidAPI-Key: c07540b849msh5f1b436e04531f9p167645jsn27e8********",
        "Accept-Encoding: application/gzip",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host: google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com"
    )
    suspend fun getTranslate(
        @Query("q") q: String,
        @Query("target") target: String,
        @Query("source") source: String,
    ): Response<String>
}
```

I'm probably sure that my api key is valid but i don't know why my project is still has an error.
I'm new with retrofit so please give me a guide to fix this issue